# JavaFX - Why is the score not incrementing?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: the game]

I just added the animation part and now whenever I click on the duck it does nothing to the score, but when I comment out the animation code and the duck stays still, it increments just fine.

[Full Code](http://pastebin.com/0gL3Z1DK)

Animation:

```
KeyValue start = new KeyValue(duck.translateXProperty(), 10);
KeyValue end = new KeyValue(duck.translateXProperty(), 400);
KeyFrame startF = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, start);
KeyFrame endF = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), end);
Timeline tl = new Timeline(startF, endF);
tl.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
tl.setAutoReverse(true);
tl.play();
```

Event Handler for Clicks:

```
scene.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (duck.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())){
            //increment score
            incrementScore();
            scoreDisplay.setText(""+score+"00");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `incrementScore()` in the question.

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint inside of the `onClick`, and examine the duck's bounds, and the event's point? Do they make sense?

Comment: @Andy private void incrementScore(){ score++; }

Comment: Then I'd guess that `duck.contains` returns false.

Comment: UPDATE : Whenever I click the ducks initial position, it increments the score so I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've said in the question and comments:

> when I comment out the animation code and the duck stays still, it increments just fine

> Whenever I click the ducks initial position, it increments the score

I'm guessing that your `ImageView` (the `duck`)'s bounding box is not getting updated.

---

[From the `ImageView` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty()):

> This variable can be used to alter the location of a node **without disturbing its layoutBounds**, which makes it useful for animating a node's location.

This means that the image itself moves, and the `duck` is still considered to be at its initial position, so the `contains()` method wouldn't work. You'll have to find a different way of figuring out clicks

---

Perhaps what you could do is use the [`getTranslateX()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTranslateX()) property for your `contains()`, it seems like it'll get the current offset of the visual duck from the geometry duck:

```
scene.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    double rawMouseX = event.getX();
    double rawMouseY = event.getY();

    double normalizedMouseX = rawMouseX - duck.getTranslateX();
    double normalizedMouseY = rawMouseY - duck.getTranslateY();

    if (duck.contains(normalizedMouseX, normalizedMouseY)){
        //increment score
        incrementScore();
        scoreDisplay.setText(""+score+"00");
    }
});
```

---

**Disclaimer**: I have no experience with JavaFX, I'm going mainly off of vanilla Java experience

Comment: What do you mean bounding box and how would I fix that? Sorry if that's a dumb question but I'm new to animation in JavaFX and I'm still learning as I go.

Comment: @Zach I've updated the answer - In summary the animation moves the image, but the scene still thinks its at it's original position - I'm reading the docs right now to see if there's anything that can help, I'll let you know

Comment: @Zach I've updated with a possible answer, let me know if it works (I honestly have no idea ;])

Comment: This approach works, but it doesn't leverage any of the built-in functionality of JavaFX. Well done @Jeeter  at coming up with a workaround though

Answer (score 1):

You needn't calculate the normalized position or the mouse X/Y coordinates. You need to use the `getBoundsInParent()` method:

```
        if (duck.getBoundsInParent().contains(event.getX(), event.getY())){
            //increment score
            incrementScore();
            scoreDisplay.setText(""+score+"00");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your mouse handler on the duck, not the scene.

Also, use [pickOnBounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty) to only react when you click on the duck's pixels, not it's bounding box.

```
duck.setPickOnBounds(false);
duck.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    incrementScore();
    scoreDisplay.setText(score + "00");
});
```